# Directives with parameters in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wrote a directive with angularjs and jQuery cycle

```
<div class="slideshow" cycle>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('cycle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $(element).cycle({
               fx: 'fade',
               timeout: 10
           });
        }
    };
});
```

this directive have no problem but I want extend it with some parameters for example I need something like this

```
<div class="slideshow" cycle='fade'>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    ...
</div>
```

you can see I set **cycle='fade'**

cycle is directive and fade is my directive`s parameter for cycling effect

How i can have a directive with parameter and use it like above ?

```
<div class="slideshow" cycle='fade'> ////????????????
myApp.directive('cycle', function(effect) { ////?????????????????
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
               $(element).cycle({
                   fx: effect , ////?????????????????
                   timeout: 10
               });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`attrs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)

> A shared object between directive compile / linking functions which contains normalized DOM element attributes.

*Example*

```
$(element).cycle({
   fx: attrs.cycle,
   timeout: 10
});
```

Complete Code

*HTML*

```
<div class="slideshow" cycle='fade'>
```

*Script*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('cycle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $(element).cycle({
               fx: attrs.cycle,
               timeout: 10
           });
        }
    };
});
```

EDIT:

---

You can use isolated scope concept to pass parameters to custom directive.

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow" cycle effect='fade' timeout='10'>
```

Script

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('cycle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            effect: '=',
            timeout: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $(element).cycle({
               fx: scope.effect,
               timeout: scope.timeout
           });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: if I want to have more than one parameter How I can write this ?? for example I want to set fx effect and timeout

Comment: You can create multiple parameters or you can use scope

Comment: Can you update your post for your idea ? (HTML and script for multiple params)

Comment: @HamedF, Updated answer, Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('cycle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options : "&cycle"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $(element).cycle({
               fx: scope.options.fx,
               timeout: 10
           });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: if I want to have more than one parameter How I can write this ?? for example I want to set fx effect and timeout

Comment: on your controller you can say that $scope.cycleOpts = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'...}; 

now to use it is cycle="cycleOpts"

in your directive you can get data by scope.options.foo